# How to assign values from a different column with dynamically created columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I want to create dynamically new columns and assign values from columns starting with vz, specifically taking values from one to four months after exit_r. So for example, if exit_r is 2015-03-22 and I want to take a value after one month, I want to assign the value from a column vz201504 and assign it to a new column with index 1 (IncAfterRepas1).

```
exit_r <- as.Date(c("2015-03-22","2015-04-29","2015-05-23","2015-05-03","2015-04-29","2015-03-18","2015-07-14","2015-04-08","2015-02-11","2015-04-27"))
vz201502  <- as.numeric(c("0.00","3.00","5.00","0.00","0.00","21","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201503  <- as.numeric(c("0.00","2.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","21","21.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201504 <- as.numeric(c("500.00","5.00","8.00","0.00","0.00","21.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","482"))
vz201505 <- as.numeric(c("0.00","6.00","9.00","10.00","12.00","0.00","5.00","0.00","8.00","664 "))
vz201506 <- as.numeric(c("3.00","4.00","5.00","0.00","9.00","8.00","1.00","4.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201507 <- as.numeric(c("0.00","4.00","3.00","5.00","0.00","2.00","0.00","0.00","1.00","2.00"))
df <- data.frame(exit_r,vz201502,vz201503, vz201504, vz201505,vz201506,vz201507)
```

I created this loop but it does not work.

```
for (m in 1:4){
  df[, paste0('IncAfterRepas',m, '')] <- df[, paste0("vz", format((df$exit_r %m+% months(m)), "%Y%m"))] 
}
```

Basically, I want something like this for month 1.

```
exit_r<- as.Date(c("2015-03-22","2015-04-29","2015-05-23","2015-05-03","2015-04-29","2015-03-18","2015-07-14","2015-04-08","2015-02-11","2015-04-27"))
vz201502  <- as.numeric(c("0.00","3.00","5.00","0.00","0.00","21","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201503  <- as.numeric(c("0.00","2.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","21","21.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201504 <- as.numeric(c("500.00","5.00","8.00","0.00","0.00","21.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","482"))
vz201505 <- as.numeric(c("0.00","6.00","9.00","10.00","12.00","0.00","5.00","0.00","8.00","664 "))
vz201506 <- as.numeric(c("3.00","4.00","5.00","0.00","9.00","8.00","1.00","4.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201507 <- as.numeric(c("0.00","4.00","3.00","5.00","0.00","2.00","0.00","0.00","1.00","2.00"))
IncAfterRepas1 <- as.numeric(c("500","6.00","5.00","0.00","12.00","21","NA","0.00","0.00","664")) 
df <- data.frame(exit_r,vz201502,vz201503, vz201504, vz201505,vz201506,vz201507,IncAfterRepas1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may do what you are after. It uses the zoo library to simplify date manipulation by month.
In each loop, it calculates the YearMonth dates required, figures out the names of the column to get the data from, gets the data for the new column, being careful to replace NULL with NA, adds the new column to the existing data frame, and renames the new column.

```
for (m in 1:4){
  NextYearMonths <- as.yearmon(df$exit_r) + m/12
  RequiredColumnSource <- format(NextYearMonths,"vz%Y%m")
  NewColumn <- sapply(seq(1:nrow(df)),function(RowIndex) {
    NewData <- df[RowIndex,RequiredColumnSource[RowIndex]]
    NewData[is.null(NewData)] <- NA
    return(NewData)
    })
  df <- cbind(df,NewColumn)
  names(df)[ncol(df)] <- paste0("IncAfterRepas",m)
}


> df
       exit_r vz201502 vz201503 vz201504 vz201505 vz201506 vz201507 IncAfterRepas1 IncAfterRepas2 IncAfterRepas3 IncAfterRepas4
1  2015-03-22        0        0      500        0        3        0            500              0              3              0
2  2015-04-29        3        2        5        6        4        4              6              4              4             NA
3  2015-05-23        5        0        8        9        5        3              5              3             NA             NA
4  2015-05-03        0        0        0       10        0        5              0              5             NA             NA
5  2015-04-29        0        0        0       12        9        0             12              9              0             NA
6  2015-03-18       21       21       21        0        8        2             21              0              8              2
7  2015-07-14        0       21        0        5        1        0             NA             NA             NA             NA
8  2015-04-08        0        0        0        0        4        0              0              4              0             NA
9  2015-02-11        0        0        0        8        0        1              0              0              8              0
10 2015-04-27        0        0      482      664        0        2            664              0              2             NA
```

Comment: @Rainfall.NZ_: I am trying to adjust the date like this but it does not work, only the first row is completed. Any suggestions? Thank you. `lastCohort= as.Date("2015-01-01")
for (m in 1:4) {
  NextYearMonths <- as.yearmon(lastCohort) + m/12
  RequiredColumnSource <- format(NextYearMonths, "vz%Y%m") 
  NewColumn <- sapply(seq(1:nrow(df)), function(RowIndex)  {
    NewData <- df[RowIndex, RequiredColumnSource[RowIndex]]
    NewData[is.null(NewData)] <- NA
    return(NewData)
  });
  df <- cbind(df, NewColumn)
  names(df)[ncol(df)] <- paste0("IncAfterLastCohort", m)
}`

Comment: @Zuzana your `lastCohort` variable needs to contain all the dates that you want to process. try  `lastCohort <- df$exit_r` or `lastCohort <- exit_r`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just wanted to have one date in `lastCohort` which applies for all rows. I figured it out like this: I created a new column `df$lastCohort= as.Date("2015-01-01")` and then run the code that you provided.  It is not really straightforward but it gave me the results that I wanted.